# Сделать динамическое добавление кнопок с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток всем!
Учусь явасрипту,jquery,php.
Делаю маленький планировщик заданий, есть поле ввода информации, и есть кнопка ввода информации. Когда набрал информацию то после нажатия на кнопку, текст добавляется в список, далее я хочу сделать что бы после того как каждая информация добавилась в список то сразу появлялась еще одна кнопка которая будет называться "Завершить", далее по нажатию на данную кнопку что бы зачеркивался текст к которой это кнопка относится.

```
    <div id="todo">
        <h1>Todo list</h1>
        <input type="text" name="todo"/>
        <button>Add</button>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <?php
        foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
            if(strpos($key, "todo") === 0)
            echo "<li>" . $value . "<a href='#' id='" .  $key . "'>x</a></li>";         
        }
      ?>
      <button class="complete" style="display: none;">
    </ul>


   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

//код в файле скрипта такой:

```
 var main = function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var forTime = new Date();
        var year = forTime.getFullYear();
        var day = forTime.getDay();
        var month = forTime.getMonth();
        var hours = forTime.getHours();
        var min = forTime.getMinutes();
        var sec = forTime.getSeconds();
        var todo = $("input").val();
        var text = "время добавления задачи: ";
        if(day < 10) day = "0" + 1;
        else if (day == 0) day += 1;
        if(month < 10) month = "0" + month;
        if(min < 10) min = "0" + min;
        if(sec < 10) sec = "0" + sec;

        var li = "<li>" + todo + ". // " + text + hours + ":" + min + ":" 
        + sec + ", дата: " + day + "." + month + "." + year + " г." 
        + "<a href='#'>x</a>" + "</li>";
        $("year").css("font-size: 12px", "color: red");
        $("ul").prepend(li).addClass('border');
    }); //end onclick button

    $("a").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "remove.php",
          data: {"key": $(this).attr("id")}
       }); 
       $(this).closest("li").remove();

    }); 
}

$(document).on('click', '.complete', function(){
   $(this). 
});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Igor спасибо что подправили мой код. Я еще плохо ориентируюсь на данном сайте.